# Does not show on the price chart

Tags: display

my code is not showing anything on the price chart

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Force Index", shorttitle="Force Index", overlay=true,timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
XLen1 = input.int(3, minval=1)
XLen2 = input.int(13, minval=1)
hline(0, color=color.green)

xValue = volume * (close - close[1])
xSMA1 = ta.ema(xValue, XLen1)
xSMA2 = ta.ema(xValue, XLen2)
plot(xSMA1,style=plot.style_columns,  color=color.blue, title="Slow Avg")
plot(xSMA2, color=color.red, title="Fast Avg")
```

I want it to show on the price chart please help